# Put dot register (last inserted text) in visual mode in vim

Tags: vim

In the following code snippet I'm trying to replace parameter name from `param` to `value`, using dot register (last inserted text):

```
function execute(param){
  var result = param.paramProcessing();
  return ;
}
```

1. I place the cursor on the in first occurence of param (in the
   brackets)
2. I type `ciwvalue<ESC>` to replace `param` with `value`, and move `value` into dot register
3. I place the cursor on semicolon after return statement
4. I type `viw".P` to paste previously inserted text before semicolon
5. I go to second `param` occurence
6. I type `viw".p` to select `param`, and replace it with `value`

As you can see, the step #4 works as intended. Problem occurs at the step #6. Instead of replacing world as I expected, it causes removal of world 'param', and leaves me in visual mode.

I wish if someone could explain me what happened in step #6 (and why it doesn't work as I expected), and provide me solution to my problem similar to which I have now.

Answer (score 2):

Here, `viw".p` works as intended only if the content of the dot register doesn't start with a `v`, which sounds a lot like a bug. If that's indeed a bug, you should submit it to [Vim's issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues).

Anyway, if I were in your situation I would:

```
/param<CR>       jump to next 'param'
cgnvalue<Esc>    change the match with 'value'
.                repeat the change on next match
/;<CR>n          jump to second next ';'
".P              put the content of the dot register before the cursor
```

Comment: Thanks for next portion of fancy vim stuff to remember (especially `gn`, I haven't heard about it before). Unfortunately for me, if i try to make a change from 'param' to for example 'count' or other word that doesn't start with 'v' the result is similar. I'll post a question on vim mailing group and we will see.